# Spring AOP expression - class that contains String

Tags: java, spring, aop

I want to write an AOP expression that will fetch all classes which have a certain string in their names. Assume I have the following classes: `ProductRestController, ProductSoapController, ProductService`. I would like to write an expression that will fetch classes that have Controller in their names. Is this possible with Spring AOP?

Comment: if your Conroller have the spring annotation @Controller, you can use a pointcut like this  @Pointcut("within(@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller *)")

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have this annotation on top of my controllers. I have RestController annotation in Rest class and Endpoint in Soap class

Comment: I found this on spring documentation: any join point (method execution only in Spring AOP) on Spring beans having names that match the wildcard expression '*Controller': 

@Pointcut("bean(*Controller)")

Comment: Thank you so much! This works as expected!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match all methods defined in beans whose name ends with ‘Controller’.

```
bean(*Controller)
```